# Cupy fft causing memory leak?

Tags: python, cupy

In my python script I have some quite extensive use of fft and ifft. To speed things up with my GTX 1060 6GB I use the cupy library. After running into Out Of Memory problems, I discovered that memory leakage was the cause.

I created the following code to investigate the problem. After calling `cupy.fft.fft` more additional memory than the size of the output is allocated. When deleting that ouput, only that amount of memory is actually being released and I don't know how to release the extra memory. Is this a bug or am I overseeing something?

```
import cupy as cp


t = cp.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
print("t      :", cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()/1024, "kB")

a = cp.sin(4 * t*2*3.1415)

print("t+a    :", cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()/1024, "kB")

fft = cp.fft.fft(a)

print("fft    :", fft.nbytes/1024, "kB")
print("t+a+fft:", cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()/1024, "kB")

del fft
cp.get_default_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()
cp.get_default_pinned_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()

print("t+a    :", cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()/1024, "kB")

del t,a
print("       :", cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()/1024, "kB")
```

Output:

```
t      : 8.0 kB
t+a    : 16.0 kB
fft    : 15.625 kB
t+a+fft: 48.0 kB
t+a    : 32.0 kB
       : 16.0 kB
```

I am using cupy-cuda101 version 8.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @MazzMan I didn't notice your SO question until now. As I replied in [your ticket](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/4282), this is not a bug but rather expected behavior, as starting v8.0 we cache cuFFT plans by default. The plans are tied to some memory as workspace, so unless the plans are deleted/the cache is cleared, there will be some memory hold. You can refer to CuPy's doc on the plan cache [here](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/plan_cache.html#cupy.fft._cache.PlanCache) and try disabling the cache, for example.

In your case, you can also run the following lines after your script to confirm the memory is freed after clearing the cache.

```py
>>> cache = cp.fft.config.get_plan_cache()
>>> cache.clear()
>>> print("after clearing cache:", cp.get_default_memory_pool().used_bytes()/1024, "kB")
after clearing cache: 0.0 kB
```